# What is the maximum length of Image/Process names in Windows?

Tags: windows, process

What is the maximum length of a process/image name in Windows? I'm trying to make a program similar to Task Manager and I think this information could be useful. My guess is that it'll be the same as the maximum filename length....

Comment: Processes don't have names.  The "image name" literally *is* the name of the executable file.

Comment: Okay, thanks for confirming it